# Multiple views to one view, how do I go back to the sender

Tags: ios, xcode, view, segue, viewcontroller

I am connecting three different views to one view and I am  trying to create a back button that goes back to the view that I came from.

Example:

View A, B and C are connected to view D. I want to create a back button that goes back to say B, if I went to D from B. If I went to D from C, I want that button to go back to C and so on. How do I do this programmatically?

Here's some code:
On the sender we are using

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueA"]) {
    ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.segueName = @"SegueA";
  }
}
```

On the receiver side, we are using the following code :

```
- (IBAction)backBtn:(id)sender {
if([_segueName  isEqualToString: @"SegueA"]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueAA" sender:self];
}
```

So we are using a segue to go from A to D and then, if SegueA is identified we want to return via a segue from D to A called SegueAA.

Comment: Try providing some code for what you've done already. Also, are you doing navigation in your app using `UIView`s directly and not using `UIViewController`s? Because how it sounds, you should be using view controllers and a navigation controller, but you say nothing about them in your question.

Comment: All view controllers have navigation controllers

Comment: All view controllers have a property `navigationController`, but it is only set to something if they are contained within a `UINavigationController`, but they aren't necessarily.

Comment: AFAIK you can only use segues if you have a UINavController. Therefore it is set in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `UIViewController` instead of `UIView`, you can use

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a manual segue.  You do this by making a segue from one view to another and then giving it a name in the interface builder.

- Control Drag from one view to another
- Under the "manual" segue type you probably want to use push
- Click on the segue and go to properties and give it a name under the "Identifier" field
- Then you can call it like so:

  ```
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"initalLegalSegue" sender:self];
  ```

(this block for example would launch my "initialLegalSegue" manually by code.)

Answer (score 0):

With modal segues, I've been using this:

This goes back one view controller:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This goes back two view controllers:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```